# Run a batch command for every file in a directory

Tags: windows-xp, script, batch

I have a Java program working with this syntax:

```
command.jar namefile
```

I have to run this program for 1600 files in a directory. How can I run this command for every file automatically?

Is there a DOS batch command? Or another way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is by far to simply run a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) over all the files. The good thing is that the `set` (the input for the `for`-loop) does accept the same wildcards like the regular `cmd`.

For use in a batch file:

```
FOR %%f IN (*) DO command.jar %%f
```

For use from the command line:

```
FOR %f IN (*) DO command.jar %f
```

Comment: Hi!
It works with this:
for %f in (*) do command.jar %f

Really really thanks! :)

Comment: @E_M: Edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: This is because you have to escape the % in a batch file. To be safe you should first append 'echo' to the beginning of the command to see what exactly will be executed.