# Mac OS X: Run app on every file in folder

Tags: macos, batch

I want to use jsmin to minify every js file in a directory, and js files in subfolders as well.

I would want to use the compiled vers of jsmin found here:
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/73

What is the Mac OS X equivalent of a batch file?

Looking for something like this for Mac OS X:
[Run a batch command for every file in a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/116417/run-a-batch-command-for-every-file-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a shell script. But you don't need a script, you just need [`find`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific. I understand that the find command will find the files I need to apply to the app, but how do I write a schell script?

Comment: You probably don't need a full script. `find somedir -name '*.js' -exec minify {} \;` But if you want to learn regardless: http://steve-parker.org/sh/sh.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a variety of languages (Python, Ruby, Perl) but as Ignacio pointed out its easiest to do this with plain 'ol `find` passing the files to minify.

[Man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) for `find`

[Beginners guide](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/find.php) to using `find`.

Find will recurse through directories and pass their paths to minify, or yui-compressor or whatever you plan on using. You could then also [concat (`cat`) those minified files](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cat.1.html) into a single file.

You might also be interested in projects like [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/) which automates this type of task for web development.

I usually automate tasks like this with [Rake](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) - even though Rake is written in Ruby I use it to deploy PHP sites, minify and concat JavaScript, etc.